# Value is possibly undefined even if I have a user defined type guard to check that it is not

Tags: typescript

In the code below I use a user defined type guard to check that `val` is not defined (by returning early if it is). The type script compiler does not seem to pick up on this. I get a warning when I try to use `val` as a string that `Object is possibly 'undefined`.

```
function isUndefined(val: any): val is undefined {
  return typeof val === "undefined";
}

function calculateFontSize(el: SVGElement) {
  const val = getPresentationAttribute(el, "font-size");
  if (isUndefined("val")) {
    return null;
  }
  // const val: string | undefined; Object is possibly 'undefined'.
  return Number.parseFloat(val.replace("px", ""));
}
```

Why does TypeScript not pick up on the type from my user defined type guard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in `val`, not `"val"`:

```
  if (isUndefined(val)) {
    return null;
  }
```